# NixOS - Let's Encrypt certificate is not recognized by Traefik (works in Nginx)

Tags: ssl, reverse-proxy, lets-encrypt, traefik, nixos

I am trying to run a demo Node.js app on a subdomain using Traefik reverse proxy. I am generating the wildcard Let's Encrypt certificate with the security.acme option. When I import the certificate in the Nginx config, it works correctly. However, when I try to add it to Traefik, I get the following error:

> Secure Connection Failed
>
> An error occurred during a connection to hello.domain.com SSL peer has no certificate for the requested DNS name.
>
> Error code: SSL_ERROR_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME_ALERT
>
> ```
> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because the authenticity of the received data could not be verified.
> Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.
> ```

Here is my configuration.nix:

```
{ pkgs, ... }: {
  # imports = [ ... ];

  config = {
    environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
      openssl
      git
      nodejs
      yarn
      nodePackages.npm
    ];

    security.acme = {
      acceptTerms = true;
      defaults.email = "name@domain.com";
      certs."domain.com" = {
        domain = "domain.com";
        extraDomainNames = [ "*.domain.com" ];
        dnsProvider = "ovh";
        dnsPropagationCheck = true;
        credentialsFile = "/etc/nixos/credentials.txt";
      };
    };

    services.traefik = {
      enable = true;
      staticConfigOptions = {
        global = {
          checkNewVersion = false;
          sendAnonymousUsage = false;
        };
        entryPoints = {
          web = {
            address = ":80";
            http.redirections.entrypoint = {
              to = "websecure";
              scheme = "https";
            };
          };
          websecure.address = ":443";
        };
        providers.docker.exposedByDefault = false;
      };
      dynamicConfigOptions = {

        tls = {
            stores.default = {
              defaultCertificate = {
                certFile = "/var/lib/acme/domain.com/cert.pem";
                keyFile = "/var/lib/acme/domain.com/key.pem";
              };
            };

            certificates = [
              {
                certFile = "/var/lib/acme/domain.com/cert.pem";
                keyFile = "/var/lib/acme/domain/key.pem";
                stores = "default";
              }
            ];
          };

        http.routers.hello = {
          rule = "Host(`hello.domain.com`)";
          entryPoints = [ "websecure" ];
          service = "hello";
          tls = true;
        };

        http.services.hello = {
          loadBalancer.servers = [{
            url = "http://localhost:8000";
          }];
        };

      };

    };


    systemd.services."hello-world" = {
      description = "Hello World";
      after = [ "network.target" ];
      wantedBy = [ "multi-user.target" ];
      serviceConfig = {
        Type = "simple";
        ExecStart = "${pkgs.nodejs}/bin/node /etc/nixos/app.js";
        Restart = "always";
        RestartSec = "3";
      };
    };

    networking.firewall.allowedTCPPorts = [ 80 443 8000 ];
    users.users.traefik.extraGroups = [ "docker" ];
  };
}
```

When I comment out this part:

```
       #  stores.default = {
       #      defaultCertificate = {
       #       certFile = "/var/lib/acme/domain.com/cert.pem";
       #       keyFile = "/var/lib/acme/domain.com/key.pem";
       #    };
       #  };
```

I get a "Warning: Potential Security Risk Ahead," but I can reach the subdomain page. This is because Traefik uses the default certificate then:

```
| Common Name (CN)|TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT|
|---|---|
|Organization (O)|<Not Part Of Certificate>|
|Organizational Unit (OU)|<Not Part Of Certificate>|
|Common Name (CN)|TRAEFIK DEFAULT CERT|
|Organization (O)|<Not Part Of Certificate>|
|Organizational Unit (OU)|<Not Part Of Certificate>|
|Issued On|Monday, May 29, 2023 at 10:48:12 AM|
|Expires On|Tuesday, May 28, 2024 at 10:48:12 AM|
```

How can i fix my config to use Let's encrypt wildcard certificate with Treafik correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in the path to the key file for the wildcard certificate, here would be the correct version:

```
certificates = [
  {
    certFile = "/var/lib/acme/domain.com/cert.pem";
    keyFile = "/var/lib/acme/domain.com/key.pem";
    stores = "default";
  }
];
```

Comment: Thanks, for pointing the path typo. It seems that was only present in Stack Overflow it question, when changed the domain. I got my config working anyway. I was testing Caddy as reverse proxy, i then disabled. When i re-enabled Traefik it started working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed. Here is the working config for the reference:

```
{ pkgs, ... }: {
  # imports = [ ... ];

  config = {
    environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
      openssl
      git
      nodejs
      yarn
      nodePackages.npm
    ];

    security.acme = {
      acceptTerms = true;
      defaults.email = "name@domain.com";
      certs."domain.com" = {
        domain = "domain.com";
        extraDomainNames = [ "*.domain.com" ];
        dnsProvider = "ovh";
        dnsPropagationCheck = true;
        credentialsFile = "/etc/nixos/credentials.txt";
      };
    };

    services.traefik = {
      enable = true;



      staticConfigOptions = {
        global = {
          checkNewVersion = false;
          sendAnonymousUsage = false;
        };


        entryPoints = {
          web = {
            address = ":80";
            http.redirections.entrypoint = {
              to = "websecure";
              scheme = "https";
            };
          };
          websecure = {
            address = ":443";

          };

        };
        providers.docker.exposedByDefault = false;
      };
      dynamicConfigOptions = {


        tls = {
          stores.default = {
            defaultCertificate = {
              certFile = "/var/lib/acme/domain.com/cert.pem";
              keyFile = "/var/lib/acme/domain.com/key.pem";
            };
          };

          certificates = [
            {
              certFile = "/var/lib/acme/domain.com/cert.pem";
              keyFile = "/var/lib/acme/domain.com/key.pem";
              stores = "default";
            }
          ];
        };




        http.routers.hello = {
          rule = "Host(`hello.domain.com`)";
          entryPoints = [ "websecure" ];
          service = "hello";
          tls = {
            certResolver = "my-resolver";
            domains = {
              main = [ "domain.com" ];
              sans = [ "*.domain.com" ];
            };
          };
        };

        http.services.hello = {
          loadBalancer.servers = [{
            url = "http://localhost:8000";
          }];
        };

      };


    };



    # services.caddy = {
    #   enable = true;

    #   virtualHosts."hello.domain.com".extraConfig = ''
    #     reverse_proxy http://localhost:8000
    #   '';

    #   extraConfig = ''
    #     domain.com {
    #       root * /var/www
    #       file_server
    #     }

    #   '';
    # };

    virtualisation.docker.enable = true;
    systemd.services.copy-landing-page = {
      description = "Copy index";
      wantedBy = [ "multi-user.target" ];
      serviceConfig = {
        Type = "oneshot";
        ExecStart = "${pkgs.coreutils}/bin/cp ${./html/index.html} /var/www/index.html";
      };
    };

    systemd.services."hello-world" = {
      description = "Hello World Node.js app";
      after = [ "network.target" ];
      wantedBy = [ "multi-user.target" ];
      serviceConfig = {
        Type = "simple";
        ExecStart = "${pkgs.nodejs}/bin/node /etc/nixos/app.js";
        Restart = "always";
        RestartSec = "3";
      };
    };



    networking.firewall.allowedTCPPorts = [ 80 443 8000 ];
    users.users.traefik.extraGroups = [ "docker" "acme" ];
    #    users.users.traefik = {
    #   isSystemUser = false;
    #   isNormalUser = true;
    #   group = "traefik";
    # };

  };
}
```

credentials.txt

```
OVH_APPLICATION_KEY=<key>
OVH_APPLICATION_SECRET=<key>
OVH_CONSUMER_KEY=<key>
OVH_ENDPOINT=ovh-eu
```